# SQL Query returns unexpected NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

When running a SQL query I am getting a strange NULL result. Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM plan LEFT JOIN bill ON plan.planID = bill.planID AND bill.typeID =3 WHERE bill.billID IS NULL
```

I am running the query in PHP using a PDO object. All of the results are coming out as such:

```
Array ( [planID] => [0] => 7 [clientID] => 4 ...)
```

The problem lies within the first value returned. As you can see PlanID is NULL but when the same value is pulled with the numeric key, it appears properly as "7". I have tried to address the issue by adding `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to the query code, but I get the following result:

```
Array ( [planID] => [clientID] => 4 ...)
```

I do not understand how or why this is occurring. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: And you're **100% certain** you have no null values in your `plan` table?

Comment: Yes, I have pulled up several lines on the back end that match the lines pulled by my PHP and they have the proper PlanID shown in the `[0]=> 7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is your problem, but when you say:

```
select *
from . . .
```

it is returning *all* columns from *all* tables.  This means that there are two columns called `planId` in the results, one from `plan` and one from `bill`.  The one from `bill` is `NULL`, assuming that the purpose of the `where` clause is to find non-matches.  That may be the one that you are seeing.

The solution is to explicitly choose the specific columns that you want.  Perhaps:

```
select plan.planId
from . . .
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's legal in mysql, but in oracle you can do `table.*` to pull from a specific table.

Comment: Good Point, doing some testing now.